# iOS Facebook SDK - How to get facebook manage_pages permission to get facebook pages managed by user?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch Facebook Pages list managed by user. And also want to fetch user managed groups in facebook. Can anyone have idea for this? I have tried to get "manage_pages" permission and "/me/accounts" facebook graph api but failed to get any data.

Comment: if its private you can't get the details

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I have checked in Graph API explorer and it gives me proper data on all facebook pages & groups list. But same graph API is not working on my iOS code. Do you think it is an issue of access token?

Comment: may be.............

Comment: @NishaParmanandani Did you select your own app from the top right? If you browse as the Graph Explorer itself, you will always get more data.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian Yes, I have selected my app from the top right in graph explorer. It works fine in Graph Explorer, but not working in ios app side code.

Comment: Did you retrieve a page access token after you got your user access token? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian Thanks for the help. I successfully manage to get page list by calling me/accounts graph api with parameter type "page".